# Patterns for transient user notifications with Relay

Tags: relayjs

I have some mutations where (for reasons outside of my control), the result  isn't immediately apparent in my data layer, so I can't read it from the graph after performing the operation. I would like to be able to show a notification/alert to the user to indicate that the operation was successful and also to provide some information to them that was generated during the mutation (in this case, it's a tracking code provided by a 3rd-party API). Outside of this example, i'm sure there'll be other cases where I want to show notifications of various types (success, info, warning, error) to the user.

Mutation responses only include requested information in the output fields, so the obvious strategy to me is have a `TransientNotification` type that's also returned in the output. But it feels strange to do it in the GraphQL schema because the data doesn't actually get stored anywhere.

So i'm looking for ideas for the best way to approach this. It's a fairly common UI pattern, and it currently feels like i'm having to jump through a *lot* of hoops to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In general, returning field in the mutation response containing the notification (`TransientNotification`) seems like a reasonable approach here. You can use [mutation query fragments](http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-mutation.html#fragments-static-property) to ensure that this field is fetched by the component that triggers the mutation, and then the data will be available to display in the UI.

Comment: Thanks. This is the route i've been going doing. The main gotcha I've hit is that conceptually I have a list of these TransientNotifications, so I want to append the result, but RANGE_ADD only seems to work with full-blown connections, and all I have is an array.

Comment: Okay, i'm having some serious difficulty getting this to work. And it's already far beyond the complexity i'd expect for implementing success/error notifications

Comment: @AndrewIngram can you link to a gist (or paste directly) with your mutation definition and how you're calling it?